# Why do I have an endless loop and how do I do it differently?

Tags: c++

just learn .. and i can't understand what i did wrong
I just try to count the number of char in my string.

the while loop does not end - endless loop

this is the code

```
int main() {
    char buffer[255] = { 0 };
    sprintf_s(buffer, "hello world");
    char* ptr = buffer;
    int count = 0;
    while (ptr != null)
    {
        count++;
        ptr++;
    }

    std::cout << count << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

btw - i don't want to use strlen or some build in function.

Comment: you have the wrong syntax for sprintf_s ... does this compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically your pointer will never be null.

What you're looking for is to check if it points to the null terminator of the string, which is very different, and is checked by doing e.g. `*ptr == '\0'`. Notice the use of dereference operator `*` to get the value that `ptr` is currently pointing at.

---

Practically the pointer will at some time reach the end of the range for its size, overflow and become zero which is a null pointer. But if you're on a 64-bit system that might be very far away, and way beyond the end of the string.

Comment: Or the compiler decided you are writing madness and decided to ignore the condition :)

Comment: @user463035818 Running off the end of an array isn't even defined. You may form a pointer to one-past-the-end, but only for comparison purposed `(ptr != end)`, it can't be dereferenced (`*end` is illegal).

Comment: @MSalters can't be dereferenced, but maybe compared to `null` as in `ptr != null_ptr` ?